# Dynamically CSS Generate PHP function

Tags: php, css

I created a simple function to print css dynamically. I think there would be a better solution about it without using sass or less.So, Could anyone recommend me a better way?

**These are css selectors, properties & values.**

```
$css_opts = array(
    'topbar' => array(
        'selector' => '#topbar',
        'property' => array(
            array(
                'property_name'  => 'color',
                'property_value' => '#fff',
            ),
            array(
                'property_name'  => 'background-color',
                'property_value' => '#fff',
            ),
            array(
                'property_name'  => 'border-color',
                'property_value' => '#fff',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'main-bg' => array(
        'selector' => '#main-bg',
        'property' => array(
            array(
                'property_name'  => 'color',
                'property_value' => '#fff',
            ),
            array(
                'property_name'  => 'background-color',
                'property_value' => '#fff',
            ),
            array(
                'property_name'  => 'border-color',
                'property_value' => '#fff',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

**This is css generated functions**

```
function zb_css_dynamically( $css_opts ) {

    if ( isset( $css_opts ) ) {

        foreach ( $css_opts as $key => $value ) {

            if ( isset( $value['selector'] ) ) {

                echo $value['selector'];
                echo '{';

                foreach ( $value['property'] as $property ) {

                    echo $property['property_name'] . ':' . $property['property_value'] . ';';

                }
                echo '}';


            }

        }
    }

}
```

The reason I create this functions is to avoid multi time condition check in php file in css. For example, if I have a file name is custom-style.php. See below, how conditional could make me busy all the time whenever I would like to add a new css property.

```
<?php header( "Content-type: text/css" );

require_once( '../../../../../wp-load.php' );


?>

<?php if ( function_exists( 'smarkt_data' ) ) {
    $opts = fw_get_db_customizer_option(); ?>

    /*** Site Color ***/
    .main-bg {
    <?php
    if ( ! empty( $opts['site_main_color_field'] ) ) {
        echo 'background-color:' . $opts['site_main_color_field'] . ';';
    }

    ?>
    }

    .main-text-color {
    <?php
    if ( ! empty( $opts['site_main_text_color_field'] ) ) {
        echo 'color:' . $opts['site_main_text_color_field'] . ';';
    }

    ?>
    }
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know it's not an answer :D but I'd rather do it with JS. Are you sure there wouldn't be a way to keep that in the local storage (eventually change it with ajax) and just apply it? As php should be mostly separated by the front end.

Answer (score 0):

add header Content type css top of the page ..

```
header("Content-type: text/css");
```

Don't forgot to create a new php file that'ii be dedicated for dynamic css file .

Comment: I don't think it is better way when we have so many css selector are dynamically. Check my question ( edited) again to make you better understand.

Comment: Trying to find somthing !